# Unable to change view background color

Tags: ios, swift

I have this base class `BaseController` where I change the view background color

```
self.view.backgroundColor = 
    UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0)
```

in the `viewDidLoad()` method

```
import UIKit

class BaseController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0)

    }

    func UIColorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32, alpha:Double=1.0)->UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
        let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0

        return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

And here is `MainController` which extends `BaseController` and is my entry point

```
import UIKit

class MainController: BaseController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 37/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0)
    }
}
```

But the background color of `MainController` view doesn't change, except when I manually select a color on the utilities pane.

How do I change the background color dynamically using the parent class?

Comment: What color do you actually see in `MainController`? Is it the bright green of `BaseController` or some other default color (is it white or black)?

Comment: @rmaddy I see black when I set the default color to no-color (with the red stripe in the utilities pane), and I see the dynamically applied color (in this case green) does not override the color set via the utilities pane, if that makes sense.

Comment: You're setting alpha to 0.

Comment: @AuRis Good catch. I didn't scroll to the right enough to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alpha value is set to 0 in both backgroundColor assignments, this will make the color completely clear